# Featuretools /woodwork :'Entity' object has no attribute 'ww'

Tags: featuretools

featuretools==0.27.1

woodwork==0.10.0

Anyone has ideas?

```
es_1 = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
es_1['products'].ww
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/g4/vy8nqymx22d7vgsp0_62gqfw0000gn/T/ipykernel_32148/105268139.py in 
----> 1 es_1['products'].ww

AttributeError: 'Entity' object has no attribute 'ww'

[image: guild of 1.3.0 pdf]

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade Featuretools to Version 1.0.0 or newer. Woodwork is used in Featuretools starting in Version 1.0.0. If you installed Featuretools with pip you can upgrade to the latest version with:

`pip install --upgrade featuretools`